# Not getting the expected output in strings

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to remove vowels from a string and then printing it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string orig;
    string temp;
    cin >> orig;

    for(int i=0 ; i<orig.size() ; i++){

        if(orig[i] != 'a' || orig[i] != 'A' ||orig[i] != 'e'||orig[i] != 'E'||orig[i] != 'i'||orig[i] != 'I'||
        orig[i] != 'o'||orig[i] != 'O'||orig[i] != 'u'||orig[i] != 'U'){

            temp += orig[i];

        }
    }
    cout<<temp;
    return 0;
    }
```

But this program is printing the same input string without any change. I am not getting, where things going wrong.

Comment: The opposite of `orig[i] == 'a' || orig[i] == 'A' || ...` is *not* `orig[i] != 'a' || orig[i] != 'A' || ...`. Please read about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks man, that was a very silly mistake.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to not to include the vowels you should be using `&&` not `||`.

```
    if (orig[i] != 'a' || orig[i] != 'A' ||orig[i] != 'e'||orig[i] != 'E'||orig[i] != 'i'||orig[i] != 'I'||
    orig[i] != 'o'||orig[i] != 'O'||orig[i] != 'u'||orig[i] != 'U')
```

should be

```
    if(orig[i] != 'a' && orig[i] != 'A' && orig[i] != 'e' && orig[i] != 'E' && orig[i] != 'i'&& orig[i] != 'I'&& 
    orig[i] != 'o'&& orig[i] != 'O'&& orig[i] != 'u'&& orig[i] != 'U')
```

Comment: Alternatively, just `!std::strchr("aeiou", std::tolower(orig[i]))`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `or` operators instead of `and`s. What you want to check is that the certain letter is none of the vowels, that is, not 'a' and not 'A' and not 'e'...
Swap the `||` with `&&` and you'll have it.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string orig;
    string temp;
    cin >> orig;

    for(int i=0 ; i<orig.size() ; i++){

        if(orig[i] != 'a' && orig[i] != 'A' && orig[i] != 'e' && orig[i] != 'E' && orig[i] != 'i' && orig[i] != 'I'&& orig[i] != 'o' && orig[i] != 'O' && orig[i] != 'u' && orig[i] != 'U'){

            temp += orig[i];

        }
    }
    cout<<temp;
    return 0;
    }
```